# pd.df Boolean masking based on values in list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a df looking like this:

```
  asset                    expiry   strike right position avgCost multiplier   conId
1   ZN  2018-12-21 22:00:00+00:00   118.5   C   -120.0  0.629052    1000   328020292
2   ZN  2018-12-21 22:00:00+00:00   118.5   P   -120.0  0.610823    1000   328020755
3   ZN  2018-12-21 22:00:00+00:00   119.0   C   200.0   0.576682    1000   328020299
0   ZN  2018-12-21 22:00:00+00:00   119.0   P   200.0   0.570434    1000   328020758
```

I am looking to exclude conId's from this df that are in a list:

```
excl = [328020755, 328020292]
```

so the desired output would be:

```
  asset                    expiry   strike right position avgCost multiplier   conId
3   ZN  2018-12-21 22:00:00+00:00   119.0   C   200.0   0.576682    1000   328020299
0   ZN  2018-12-21 22:00:00+00:00   119.0   P   200.0   0.570434    1000   328020758
```

Since `pd.mask()` and `pd.where()` are deprecated I am looking for a solution not using those.
Any pointer would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least a couple of ways:

#### `query`

```
res = df.query('conId not in @excl')
```

#### `loc`

```
res = df.loc[~df['conId'].isin(excl)]
```

Comment: I like the `isin()` approach. thanks for that! much appreciated. Should have found that myself.....

Answer (score 1):

You can invert isin() with a `-`:

```
df[-df['conId'].isin(excl)]
```

Complex selections can be performed by mapping over the column of interest:

```
df[df['conId'].map(lambda x: x not in excl)]
```